# How to show two different random images in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

i need to show 2 different random images.
i tried this code but the second image, show the same image of the first.
i have to replicate this but with 15 random images.
http://www.kometschuh.de/Example-Random-CSS3-Image-Flip-Effect.html
 for each `<li>` i need to show 2 different random images

```
<ul class="flip">
  <?php
    $all_images = glob("wp-content/themes/connexia/img-test/{*.jpg, *.JPG, *.JPEG, *.png, *.PNG}", GLOB_BRACE);

    shuffle($all_images);

    foreach ($all_images as $index => $image ) {
     if ($index == 15) break;  // Only print 15 images
     $image_name = basename($image);
     $image_name2 = basename($image++);
     echo "<li>
               <img src='/wp-content/themes/connexia/img-test/{$image_name}' />
               <img src='/wp-content/themes/connexia/img-test/{$image_name2}' />
          </li>";
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$imagesDir = 'images/tips/';

$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)]; // See comments
```

You can send a 2nd argument to array_rand() to get more than 1.

Also have a look at these links:

http://askwebexpert.com/tutorials/how-to-display-random-images-from-a-directory-using-php/

[php generate random image from a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876075/php-generate-random-image-from-a-directory)

[PHP pull random image from folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261978/php-pull-random-image-from-folder)

Comment: i have to replicate this but with 15 random images.
http://www.kometschuh.de/Example-Random-CSS3-Image-Flip-Effect.html
 for each <li> i need to show 2 different random images

Comment: You can still use this, request 2 random images for each <li> iteration